# Cocoa: How to show a window un-modally?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsapplication

I have un-checked the "**Visible At Launch**" option for the default window in **MainMenu.xib** file. But then, I could not find out how to show it programmatically...

Do anyone know how to show this window, **un-modally**?

Thank you at advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should build an connection from this window to an IBOutlet variate. Then you can use this variate to make window visible by calling the "orderFront:" method, just like "[window orderFront:self];". Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/OpeningClosingWindows.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate your window and make sure its on top of other windows you need to call  `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`. This will ensure that your window pops up on all other windows(even from other windows). `orderFront` will not make your window the key window(i.e the topmost/active window)

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/makeKeyAndOrderFront: